# How to incorporate the conversational context into LUIS?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I know Microsoft Luis is basically a black box that takes the utterances as input and outputs a JSON object which contains 1) a list for the entities, 2) a list for all the intents along with their scores.

My question is that how can I take the conversational context into consideration when Luis is processing its outputs.

> For example, for the sentence "Yes, I am interested in coding", I want
>   it to have different intents according to the contexts.
>
> In "context a", it is supposed to be intent "positive_confirmation";
>
> In "context b", it is supposed to be intent "user_preference".

Is this can be achieved by LUIS? or Is there any other way to realize it?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not create 2 intents and provide different examples (with different contexts) for both intents?

Comment: What do you mean by feeding it with different context? For example, we have context "ask_for_yes_no" and "ask_for_interest" and the same response from user "Yes, I am interested in coding". Are you suggesting feeding information like "ask_for_yes_no:Yes, I am interested in coding" and "ask_for_interest:Yes, I am interested in coding"?

Comment: I see, I think you can make use of Luis actions feature, there you can build conversations and keep the context

Comment: I think keeping the context would be your job. With actions you can keep context only if some parameter is missing. But in your case the statement is complete, so using actions seems difficult.